# Problems while using relative path in order to make a link to another file

Tags: java, itext

I have been trying to write a program which will make a PDF file with links using iText the following is the code snippet from that program:

```
private Chapter generatePDF(String text, String path) {
    Phrase phrase = new Phrase(text);

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();      
    paragraph.add(phrase);        

    Chapter chapter =  new Chapter(paragraph, 1);
    chapter.setNumberDepth(0);

    Chunk trial = null;
    String name = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, path.length());

    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        trial = new Chunk(i + ". " + name);
        trial.setAnchor(path);
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        para.add(trial);
        chapter.add(para);
    }

    return chapter;
 }
```

The `text` in the method above holds the value of the name of the file and the `path` contains the complete path. But I need to use only the relative path for a file.

Can anyone suggest as to what changes I need to make in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at the [java.nio.file.Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) interface.

There you find many utility functions like [Path#getFileName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName--), what is exactly what you should use here.

**Example:**

```
final Path inputFile = Paths.get("D:\\temp\\inputFile.txt");    

System.out.println(inputFile.getFileName());
```

Output:

> inputFile.txt

Answer (score 0):

Provided you use Java 7:

```
final String fileName = Paths.get(path).getFileName().toString();
```